# Uploading Home Automation Apps on AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, submission, home-automation

I have made one home automation application for iPhone/iPad.
For interaction, we have to communicate with one external device.
Now my question is while submitting this application to AppStore, what information should I provide ?
Since they won't be able to test the behavior of application and might reject the app.
Or do I have to provide them the software which interacts with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Apple can not test your App, they will reject it. If your App requires communicating with a physical device, write a web-based simulator or something Apple can connect to from the reviewer's office. Make sure you write all required information for testing into the "Notes for reviewer" field when submitting the App. That's what I did for one of my Apps and it worked fine.